# Modify VM system configuration without turning it on. Will it be OK?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, migration, cloud-computing

I am using Virtual Box.

I make a Virtual machine with this specification:

```
Base memory       : 1024 MB
Processor         : 2 CPU
OS                : Ubuntu
```

Everything is working well.

Later on, I will migrate the *.vdi to the cloud system.
However, just exactly before that, I change the VM setting to be:

```
Base memory       : 32 GB
Processor         : 4 CPU
OS                : Ubuntu
```

I do not turn on the VM again before I migrate it to the cloud system.

Will this image works in the cloud system? Is there any drawback for doing this? Will it be OK?

Comment: you don't have to ask for answers...

Comment: @Ramhound, OK. Sorry for that

Comment: After a while, may I know your comment about this subject, @Ramhound